# Faz algum sentido em usar legendas em um áudio?

Tags: html

Bom, obviamente uma legenda é usada em um vídeo ou em um jogo para que o texto possa acompanhar a imagem conforme tenha algum diálogo ou tradução, etc.
Pode ser que eu esteja errado, mas na minha cabeça não faz sentido usar o elemento `<track>` junto com o elemento `<audio>` já que uma legenda requer algum componente visual para poder fazer sentido o seu uso, já um elemento de `<audio>` não tem nenhum componente visual, então não faz sentido usar o elemento `<track>` junto com o elemento `<audio>`, isso chamou muita minha atenção por ler um artigo do site do *MDN Web Docs* dizendo:

> O elemento HTML <track> é usado como filho dos elementos de mídia <audio> e <video>.

**Fonte:** [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track)

Qual é o sentido de usar o elemento `<track>` em um elemento `<audio>`, foi um erro de entendimento meu, por favor, alguém me explica isso?

Comment: E se a pessoa for deficiente auditivo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Lógico que faz sentido, não seria ótimo poder escutar um podcast em inglês enquanto aparecem legendas em português?***

Cara sem ofensas, mas parece que vc não entendeu bem as coisas envolvidas na tag `<track>`.

**Ela é MUITO, mas do que só legendas...**

Ela tem muitos outros atributos para garantir uma boa acessibilidade e SEO do seu conteúdo. Na tag `track` vc tb pode definir o idioma do conteúdo do `track` (`srclang="en"`) e pode por exemplo fazer um "alt" usando o `descriptions` para dar detalhes do que se espera encontrar no conteúdo do áudio para cada idioma, etc.

```
<audio src="foo.ogg">
    <!-- legendas -->
    <track kind="captions" src="ingles.vtt" srclang="en" label="Inglês">
    <track kind="captions" src="japones.vtt" srclang="jp" label="Japonês">
    <track kind="captions" src="japones.vtt" srclang="pt-br" label="Português">
    <!-- descrição -->
    <track kind="descriptions" src="DescricaoIngles.vtt" srclang="en">
    <track kind="descriptions" src="DescricaoJapones.vtt" srclang="jp">
    <track kind="descriptions" src="DescricaoPortugues.vtt" srclang="pt-br">
</audio>
```

Então mesmo para quem enxerga, vc poder escutar um áudio em Japonês, e ler uma legenda em Português, isso seria MUITO interessante não acha?

Sua visão ficou muito limitada, tem gente que não enxerga com os olhos e sim com um leitor de  tela, e tem gente que enxerga com os olhos, mas não escuta. Mas isso não impede de se usar o `track` para otimizar o SEO e ser mais inclusivo.

Comment: sim, mas no caso da legenda se eu usar em um áudio, a onde elas serão exibidas?

Comment: Essa parte que não ficou muito clara para mim!

Comment: @ledeveloper não importa se é áudio ou vídeo, questão de acessibilidade e a tag track não é só para colocar legendas como falei, ela tem discriptions, langs e vários outros atributos. As "legendas" do audio vão ser lidas pelo leitor de tela por exemplo. As vezes esse artigo pode te interessar, lá eles explicam como capturar as tags track e manipular o conteúdo com JS https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/track/basics/ nesse outro artigo tb tem umas coisas interessantes https://html.com/tags/track/

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo pela atenção em ajudar! agora ficou mais claro :)

Comment: "*Sua visão ficou muito limitada*" - a piadinha foi intencional? :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo eu usei [ironic-mode-on] nessa parte 

Comment: Eu testei o seu exemplo, mas o que está sendo acessível para o usuário que não consegue ouvir?

Comment: @Miriancherbo a legenda do áudio/vídeo, o arquivo `.vtt`

Comment: @hugocsl, ok :|